# A square with the side length of pi.

Tags: pi

I want to cut out a square with the side length pi. What is the most accurate method to do so?

P.S. you cannot use the already known fact that pi is approximately 3.14159…

Comment: Draw a circle with radius $1$, wrap a thread around the upper semicircle, the length of this thread is then $\pi$.

Comment: Or you could roll the piece of paper you want to cut into a cylinder with diameter 1 unit and then cut it. I don't know about accurate though.

Comment: If you're allowed to use the continued fraction convergents $\ \frac{a_n}{b_n}\ $, you can always construct the $\ b_n^\text{th}\ $ part of a line of length $\ a_n\ $ with just a ruler and compass and a given line segment of length one.

Comment: $\pi$ in what units? Draw a square and define the length to be $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Using ruler and compasses:

Draw a circle of radius 1 and draw a diameter across it.  Draw a perpendicular to the diameter positioned at the centre of the circle, so you now have a circle with four quadrants.  Then repeatedly bisect the angle in one quadrant.  After, say, three bisections you will have an angle of $\frac{\pi}{2} \times \frac{1}{2^3} = \frac{\pi}{16}$.  Set the compasses to the length of the small chord and along a new line mark off in succession sixteen such lengths.  The total length then marked along the line will be approximately $\pi$ (actually 3.137 rather than 3.142).  Use more bisections to get a better approximation.